# How to add names from loaded with fileInput data to selectInput in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'd like to make an app, where users could load some data and than explore it by themselves, so, i'd like to now how pass colnames of the dataset to `selectInput`

For this i've got a simple app like this:

```
library("shiny")
library("readxl")

# Define UI 

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("TKM"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput(inputId = "input",label = "input xlsx: ", multiple = FALSE, accept = c(".xlsx"))
        ),

        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("contents")
        )
    )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

    df <- reactive({ read_xlsx(input$input$datapath) })


    output$contents <- renderTable({ head(df()) })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So, as you see, my data is a reactive input, so if i add a simple:

```
selectInput(inputId = "x", label = "X: ", choices = colnames(df()))
```

i woun't be able to run an app with:
`Error in df() : argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Any idias how cfan i pass the names of my df to selectInput?

Comment: Please see `?df` (function from `library(stats)`): `Density, distribution function, quantile function and random generation for the F distribution`. Please use e.g. `DF` as name for your reactive instead.

Comment: You need to use dynamic UI. Have a look at `uiOutput`. Example: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows.

```
library("shiny")
library("readxl")

# Define UI 

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("TKM"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "input", label = "input xlsx: ", multiple = FALSE, accept = c(".xlsx"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("columns"),
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- eventReactive(input$input, { 
    read_xlsx(input$input$datapath) 
  })

  output$columns <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    selectInput("x", "Choose a column", choices = colnames(df()))
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(df())
    head(df()) 
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```